# CakePHP field has fieldname in as a value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

On a page I have this form:

```
<form action="/store_collections/create" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data[test]" placeholder="Create new collection" class="span2">
</form>
```

I submit the form which sends it to the StoreCollectionsController:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class StoreCollectionsController extends AppController {

public function create() {
    print_r($this->request->data);

}
```

The `print_r` returns this:

```
Array
(
     [test] => fdsdata[test]=fds
)
```

**How is this possible??** The field's name is appended to the value. The value should be `fds` but it's `fdsdata[test]=fds`.

Any ideas? I removed everything from the controller ($uses...) to see what it could be. All the other forms on the site is fine. Just the data submitted to this controller.

Comment: Why arent you using the form helper to generate and output the form?

Comment: I'm using FormHelper. I just took a snippet/example of the main elements as an example. The issue is the field value has the field name. Same thing happens if I actually have the text field named `data[StoreCollection][title]`. The `$this->request->data` doesn't care at this point if the model is in the input name or not...

Comment: Update: Ok. The FormHelper did help a bit but it's mainly because it inserts `<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></div>`. It must be a security thing. I'll read up on it. Will update once I have more info. It's weird though. My other forms don't have the `_method` field and work nicely.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing. But the above works fine for me. the result is correct (I used 2.3 though). Also, if you actually used the FormHelper, the field would be "name="data[Modelname][test]"

Comment: Show us your code in the view. The field name being created is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input control Name property in your example above is missing the name of the model. Are you using the form helper to create the form on the view? Try this in your view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('StoreCollection'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('test'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('submit'); ?>
```

Comment: I'm using FormHelper. The form is an example.

Comment: @Bill Rollins: you forgot the submit button by entering sth in end()